# SharedPreferences and Countdown Timer: I can't save the time

Tags: android, timer, sharedpreferences, countdowntimer

I create a CountDown Timer and i use this code. (first sorry for my bad english). I use SharedPreferences to save the time when i go to another activity and return, but when i returned to the countdown activity, it restart the timer and not save anything. Can you help me please? the code used is all that!

```
public class Main8Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Myapp application ;
String eleg="";
   CountDownTimer start1;
   Button contador;
   long cont=0,q=0;
   private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment8_main);

    timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


    Button seg= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//seguir

    seg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //el a

              temporizador(q);


        }
    });
    Button par= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);//seguir

    par.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //el a

         parar();


        }
    });
    //te
    //temporizador(final long secondadd);
      temporizador(600000);



         @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                    super.onBackPressed();

                    this.finish();
            }
          public void temporizador(final long secondadd){



              start1 = new CountDownTimer(secondadd, 1000) {

                      //se ejecuta al terminar el tiempo,cuando llega a 0
                      @Override
                      public void onFinish() {
                        //contador.setText(String.valueOf(00+":"+00));
                         contador.setText("Time Elapsed: " + timeFormat.format(secondadd));
                          Toast.makeText(Main8Activity.this, "Se terminó el tiempo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cont=0;
                      }

                      //se ejecuta por cada segundo pasado
                      @Override
                      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                             contador.setText("Time Elapsed: " + timeFormat.format(secondadd));

                          contador.setText(String.format(timeFormat.format(millisUntilFinished)));
                       //  contador.setText(   String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", millisUntilFinished / 3600,(millisUntilFinished % 3600) / 60, (millisUntilFinished % 60)));
                         cont=millisUntilFinished;
                         q= millisUntilFinished;
                      }

                  }.start();


            }


        //metodo parar el cual detiene el tiempo del contador
            public void parar(){

                     start1.cancel();
            }
            //metodo ondestroy
            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();




                 parar();

            }
            //metodo onstop
            @Override
            protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();


                //se rescata el tiempo en el que se quedo
               //  int tiempokedo=Integer.parseInt((contador.getText()+"000").toString());


                 //el tiempo se guarda en un preferences
                 SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                 Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                 editor.putLong("stiem",cont);
                 editor.commit();


                 //se detiene el temporizador(tiempo)
                  parar();


            }
            //metodo onrestart
            protected void onRestart() {
                super.onRestart();

                //se rescata de preferencias el valor del tiempo el cual se quedo
                SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                int tr=preferences.getInt("stiem",0 );//re

               //se envia al temporizador con el parametro rescatado para que siga el tiempo
                temporizador(tr);



            }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you even able to compile knowing your trying to store a Long as a int without a cast etc ?

call `getLong(String key, long defValue)` instead of getInt(...) in the onRestart()